# Let X be a complex normed linear space. Then f is a complex Conti linear functional iff there is a unique real conti linear functional u on X

Tags: functional-analysis

forward implication
f is continuous therefore it is bounded hence u is bounded hence
u is a continuous.
Reverse implication:
f is expressed as function of u(x) - i((uix))
u is continuous and hence real part is continuous
imaginary part contains scalar I therefore it is also continuous.
and hence f is continuous.

f(x)=u(x)-iu(ix)

u(x)=Re(f(x)) <= |f(x)|
||u(x)|| <= ||f(x)||

now define k(x)= bar of f(x) / mod of f(x)
|F(x)|=k(x)f(x)= f(k(x)x) = Ref(k(x)x) = u(k(x)x)
and ||kx|| <= ||x||

and I don't understand how to proceed ahead

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please clarify your question: "f is a complex Conti(nuous) linear functional iff there is a unique real conti(nuous) linear functional u on X" such that what? And is uniqueness really relevant for this iff?

Answer (score 1):

Forward implication. If $f:X\to\Bbb C$ is $\Bbb C$-linear and continuous, then
$$u:=\operatorname{Re}\circ f:X\to\Bbb R$$
is $\Bbb R$-linear and continuous, and
$$\begin{align}u(x)-iu(ix)&=\operatorname{Re}(f(x))-i\operatorname{Re}(if(x))\\&=\operatorname{Re}(f(x))+i\operatorname{Im}(f(x))\\&=f(x).
\end{align}$$

Reverse implication. If $u:X\to\Bbb R$ is $\Bbb R$-linear and continuous, then
$$f:X\to\Bbb C,\quad x\mapsto u(x)-iu(ix)$$
is $\Bbb R$-linear and continuous, and
$$\begin{align}f(ix)&=u(ix)+iu(x)\\
&=i\left(u(x)-iu(ix)\right)\\
&=if(x),
\end{align}$$
so that $f$ is $\Bbb C$-linear.